# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method remove in react-plotly.js - deleteRelatedStyleRule

Tags: javascript

I am facing issue when using `react-plotly.js`. getting the below error.

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method remove in react-plotly.js - deleteRelatedStyleRule

It works fine in Chrome, error appearing only in IE. Let me know if any one had faced the same issue and any help is appreciated.

Comment: In IE9 you need to use a typedarray polyfill. See related doc: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#to-support-ie9